# Convert image to video with empty audio track

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, image-conversion

I've found a good command to convert an image to a video in FFMPEG, but each image is going to be concatenated into a longer set of videos and images, and I need concat to concatenate the audio tracks too. (Right now it's disregarding all audio tracks, probably because the images converted to videos don't have audio tracks.)

Here's the command I'm running:

> ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -f image2 -i /image.jpg -vf 'scale=640:-1' -r 30 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuvj420p out.mp4

How can I add just a simple, silent audio track in this command, or for any videos that don't have an audio track?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could possibly do everything in one command instead of making temporary videos beforehand. Can you explain the bigger picture? Are you sure the method you are pursuing is what you really need to do? The [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) may be making an appearance here.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, yes definitely. The bigger picture is that I have a set of images and videos to concatenate into one bigger video - some videos have audio tracks, some don't, images need to be played for differing durations, and there's a predefined order to the pieces of content. If there's one awesome way to do a command like this that preserves audio on video clips and keeps it all in high resolution, that would solve the problem! (Also would be great to avoid saving a bunch of temporary files, if not needed)

Comment: Can you show some info from all inputs from a typical command? Please show the complete console output of `ffmpeg -i image.jpg -i middle -i end`, etc.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard That's what I'm not completely sure on.. For example, would be like `ffmpeg -i image1.jpg -i image2.jpg -i video1noaudio.mp4 -i video2withaudio.mp4 -i image3.jpg` and somewhere in there would be `concat`, and directions for images to use `-loop 1 -f image2 -vf "scale=640:-1"`. It would also need to preserve audio from the videos with audio.

Answer (score 1):

just add `-i audio.mp3` to parameters, so the command will look like: `ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -f image2 -i /image.jpg -vf 'scale=640:-1' -r 30 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuvj420p`**`-i audio.mp3`**`out.mp4`

---

Also, here is a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779490/ffmpeg-how-to-add-new-audio-not-mixing-in-video

And here is a ffmpeg-audio manual: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MP3

Comment: This would require making `audio.mp3` first which is unnecessary because `ffmpeg` can general silent audio with the [anullsrc filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc). Also, placement matters: you're attempting to apply `-vf 'scale=640:-1' -r 30 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuvj420p` as input options to `audio.mp3`.

Comment: Figured it out with using anullsrc. Here's the command: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i anullsrc  -loop 1 -f image2 -i input1.jpg  -r 30 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -map 0:a -map 1:v input1.mp4`